# Issue of table break in outlook 2010

Tags: email, outlook

I have strange issue in my email when it is viewed in outlook 2010.

The source for the email is as follows,

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Testing</title>
</head>
<body style="background:green;border:100px solid red">
<table style="border:20px solid blue; width:600px;" align="center">
<tr>
<td>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="background:#DDD;">
<span>0</span><br /><span>1</span><br /><span>2</span><br /><span>3</span><br /><span>4</span><br /><span>5</span><br /><span>6</span><br /><span>7</span><br /><span>8</span><br /><span>9</span><br /><span>10</span><br 
/><span>11</span><br /><span>12</span><br /><span>13</span><br /><span>14</span><br /><span>15</span><br /><span>16</span><br /><span>17</span><br /><span>18</span><br /><span>19</span><br /><span>20</span><br /><span>21</span><br /><span>22</span><br /><span>23</span><br /><span>24</span><br 
/><span>25</span><br /><span>26</span><br /><span>27</span><br /><span>28</span><br /><span>29</span><br /><span>30</span><br /><span>31</span><br /><span>32</span><br /><span>33</span><br /><span>34</span><br /><span>35</span><br /><span>36</span><br /><span>37</span><br /><span>38</span><br 
/><span>39</span><br /><span>40</span><br /><span>41</span><br /><span>42</span><br /><span>43</span><br /><span>44</span><br /><span>45</span><br /><span>46</span><br /><span>47</span><br /><span>48</span><br /><span>49</span><br /><span>50</span><br /><span>51</span><br /><span>52</span><br 
/><span>53</span><br /><span>54</span><br /><span>55</span><br /><span>56</span><br /><span>57</span><br /><span>58</span><br /><span>59</span><br /><span>60</span><br /><span>61</span><br /><span>62</span><br /><span>63</span><br /><span>64</span><br /><span>65</span><br /><span>66</span><br 
/><span>67</span><br /><span>68</span><br /><span>69</span><br /><span>70</span><br /><span>71</span><br /><span>72</span><br /><span>73</span><br /><span>74</span><br /><span>75</span><br /><span>76</span><br /><span>77</span><br /><span>78</span><br /><span>79</span><br /><span>80</span><br 
/><span>81</span><br /><span>82</span><span>85</span><br /><span>86</span><br /><span>87</span><br /><span>88</span><br /><span>89</span><br /><span>90</span><br /><span>91</span><br /><span>92</span><br /><span>93</span><br /><span>94</span><br /><span>95</span><br /><span>96</span><br 
/><span>97</span><br /><span>98</span><br /><span>99</span><br /><span>100</span>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

And the email looks in outlook 2010 is as follows,

http://postimg.org/image/dpinwd9l7

In the image, you can see there is breaking of table and also border is breaked.  I don't know why it is happening.

Please help me to get rid of this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what is happening it that you are over 1800px in a single column.

You can read more about it [here](https://www.emailonacid.com/blog/article/email-development/horizontal_spacing_issues_in_outlook_2007_and_2010/):

The best answer is to break it up into two tables stacked on top of each other.